# UMVUE of parameter $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be random sample of $N(0,\sigma^2)$. how can I calculate UMVUE of parameter $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$

Comment: Your initial sentence suggests the family of distributions you're considering is $\{N(0,\sigma^2):\sigma\ge 0\}$, but you need $\sigma^2 \le 1$ in order to be able to evaluate its square root. I suspect it's not hard to show that $X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2$ is a sufficient statistic for this family of distributions, i.e. the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given that statistic is the same for all $\sigma\in[0,1]$. If you can find some crude unbiased estimator of $(1-\sigma^2)^{-n/2}$ then the conditional expected value of that estimator given the sufficient statistic will${}\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$do it, provided you can also show completeness, i.e. there is no function $g(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)$ not depending on $\sigma$ whose expected value remains $0$ regardless of changes in $\sigma$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I suspect that if you can do this it will be an example of one of the known flaws in the whole notion of unbiasedness: your best unbiased estimator will sometimes yield estimates bigger than $1$, and those are not in the parameter space. ${}\qquad{}$